# Order of initialization Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js

Regarding the following piece of code:

```
var leaderList = new app.LeaderCollection();
var leaderListView = new app.LeaderListView({collection:leaderList});

$(document).ready(function() {
    leaderList.fetch();
});
```

Why does this not work when this works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var leaderList = new app.LeaderCollection();
    var leaderListView = new app.LeaderListView({collection:leaderList});
    leaderList.fetch();
});
```

I know code shown isn't in-depth, I was wondering if anyone knew off the top of their head why these two pieces of code would behave differently.

Comment: Oh right, I forgot `fetch()` was asynchronous.  How come in the second block of code it would behave differently though?  It seems to be initializing the vars and then fetching in the right order.

Comment: The look at `app.LeaderListView` might help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue might be because of the way the `el` element behaves inside the View.

The `el` element might not have been in the `DOM` when you run it before `Document.ready` function

In the second case you are waiting for the DOM to be loaded first and then initailize your view.  Check the network tab. The response should have been dumped by the server , but the View was not ale to find the `el` to render the Models of the collection.

Comment: Oh your answer makes a lot of sense.  Thanks a lot, I believe this is the correct answer.

Comment: Glad to have helped.. Just to double check you can always open the Network tab in developer tools and check for the response.